# Flutter release apk crash

Tags: android, flutter

I am facing an issue with Flutter(v 1.17) Release APK. Debug APK is working fine. When I build Release APK the App shows white screen and it crashes and it brings following log on crash.

[image]

I have checked following links and tried the solutions listed but they didn’t worked

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48622#issuecomment-573405643

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47462

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58479

When I remove the [image_picker(^0.6.7+1)](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) plugin then the release build works fine. So it’s something related to that.

If anybody has faced similar issue kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade back the Android Gradle Plugin in your build.gradle file to 3.6.2 is working but how it work with build.gradle 4.0.0

Comment: same issue i am facing @Gursewak Singh have you find any solution

Answer (score -2):

Flutter Clean
Then Update Dependences
After That run on terminal

According to Android SDK docs you can use the following command depending on the sdkmanager location: Docs on --licenses option seems to be missing though.

yes | sdkmanager --licenses

**GNU/Linux Distributions:**

yes | ~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
**macOS**:

export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home
yes | ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
**Windows**:

%ANDROID_HOME%/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses