# flutter app not launching in from release apk

Tags: android, flutter

flutter app works just fine in android debug, ios debug and ios release. but with android release (`flutter build apk`) it just does not launch.

What I've tried:

1. lowering the gradle version from `4.1.3` to `3.6.2` [as suggested in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62259906/12555423).
2. running with `no-shrink` flag (`flutter build apk --no-shrink`).
3. setting `shrinkResources` and `minifyEnabled` to `false` in `android/app/build.gradle`

[**HERE IS A VIDEO THAT SHOWS THE ERROR CLEARLY**](https://youtu.be/oYUagh35quI)

this is my `flutter doctor -v` output:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.928], locale
    en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.0.5 at C:\Users\adnan\flutter
    • Framework revision adc687823a (3 days ago), 2021-04-16 09:40:20 -0700
    • Engine revision b09f014e96
    • Dart version 2.12.3
    • Pub download mirror https://pub.flutter-io.cn
    • Flutter download mirror https://storage.flutter-io.cn

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\adnan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.55.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\adnan\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.21.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 11 (API 30)
      (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)            • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.128
    • Edge (web)              • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 89.0.774.57

• No issues found!
```

edit: here is the error log from the android studio Logcat:

```
2021-04-20 09:58:24.300 6866-6866/? E/FlutterLoader: Flutter initialization failed.
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libflutter.so" not found
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:123)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:193)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.g.c.c(Unknown Source:23)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.a.<init>(Unknown Source:202)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.a.<init>(Unknown Source:16)
        at io.flutter.embedding.android.f.B(Unknown Source:106)
        at io.flutter.embedding.android.f.k(Unknown Source:7)
        at io.flutter.embedding.android.e.onCreate(Unknown Source:13)
        at com.myExampleApp.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libflutter.so" not found
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1087)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1008)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1664)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.loadLibrary(Unknown Source:13)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.g.c$a.a(Unknown Source:14)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.g.c$a.call(Unknown Source:0)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
2021-04-20 09:58:24.300 6866-6866/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    
    
    --------- beginning of crash
2021-04-20 09:58:24.301 6866-6866/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myExampleApp, PID: 6866
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myExampleApp/com.myExampleApp.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libflutter.so" not found
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libflutter.so" not found
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.g.c.c(Unknown Source:367)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.a.<init>(Unknown Source:202)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.a.<init>(Unknown Source:16)
        at io.flutter.embedding.android.f.B(Unknown Source:106)
        at io.flutter.embedding.android.f.k(Unknown Source:7)
        at io.flutter.embedding.android.e.onCreate(Unknown Source:13)
        at com.myExampleApp.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
     Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libflutter.so" not found
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:123)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:193)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.g.c.c(Unknown Source:23)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.a.<init>(Unknown Source:202) 
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.a.<init>(Unknown Source:16) 
        at io.flutter.embedding.android.f.B(Unknown Source:106) 
        at io.flutter.embedding.android.f.k(Unknown Source:7) 
        at io.flutter.embedding.android.e.onCreate(Unknown Source:13) 
        at com.myExampleApp.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libflutter.so" not found
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1087)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1008)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1664)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.loadLibrary(Unknown Source:13)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.g.c$a.a(Unknown Source:14)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.g.c$a.call(Unknown Source:0)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
2021-04-20 09:58:24.308 519-5643/? W/ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity com.myExampleApp/.MainActivity
2021-04-20 09:58:24.309 306-306/? W/EmuHWC2: validate: layer 37 CompositionType 1, fallback
```

(maybe duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65386544/12555423))

Comment: Another thing you can do is to open logcat in Android Studio and try to catch the error log that running the application generates.

Comment: Btw the video link does not work as it is a private video.

Comment: thank you, I'll try that, and i opened the video, thanks for that warning too.

Answer (score 2):

its a general flutter sdk and android architecture support issue as at now, waiting for a permanent fix....
but This *abifilters* solution solved the issue on emulator blue stacks emulating an LG phone for me..
Add the **ndk code** in the `defaultConfig` tag inside your ***build.gradle*** android file of your project

```
**

android {
    //...
    defaultConfig {
    ndk {
    // Filter for architectures supported by Flutter.
    abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64'
    }
    }
    }
```

**

Dont know if has drawbacks on other phones, but i will be updating this thread as we rollout and see which phones our customers who get same issues again are getting it on

**Edit,** Also Add lines below to the end of ***settings.gradle***: file to filter more..  This code will generate file **libflutter.so** on folders x86_64, arm64-v8a and armeabi-v7a. And for devices x86, then emulate arm which are the devices with the problems..

```
gradle.beforeProject({ project->
    if (project.hasProperty("target-platform") &&
            !project.getProperty("target-platform").split(",").contains("android-arm")) {
        project.setProperty("target-platform", "android-arm,android-arm64")
    }
})
```